# Filtering and Parameterizing in Visual Basic

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, parameters, textbox, reportviewer

I'm having an error which says "The Processing of FilterExpression for the tablix 'blah' cannot be performed. Cannot compare data of types System.Decimal and System.Double. Please check the data type returned by the FilterExpression."

It is working before I put the TotalDue, but after that It show's me an error.

I already did some parameters for other tablix here's what I did:

in my RDLC I have the `pIDNo, pDocID, pLname, pFname, pMI`, so on and so forth...

I have a parameter for it which is :

`@pIDno, @DocID, @Lname, @Fname, @MI, blah and blah.`

on my report viewer I put some textboxes for all the column and this is what i did:

```
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms

Public Class printall

 Private Sub parID()
        Me.PatientsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.OJTDataSet.Patients)
        Dim ID As New ReportParameter("pIDno", txtID.Text)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {ID})
        ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    End Sub

Private Sub txtID_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)    
 Handles txtID.TextChanged
        parID()
    End Sub

 Private Sub partotalDUe()
        Me.PatientsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.OJTDataSet.Patients)
        Dim TotalDue As New ReportParameter("TotalDue", txtTotalDue.Text)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {TotalDue})
        ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    End Sub

  Private Sub txtTotalDue_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtTotalDue.TextChanged
            partotalDUe()
        End Sub
```

what I did here is that I create a Private Sub for every `TextChanged`, I didn't put it here because it's kinda messy already, I did change all the Declared value in Dim and the name of the `Parameter` and also the `TextBox`.

my question now is how can I fix the TotalDue part? because the value of that in my DB is money which is like this:

1234.0000

all of the tablix works well and show's in my `ReportViewer` but the only error is the TotalDue, how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Please do guide me in here.